# Simple power tower $x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+\cdots}}}}=x$

Tags: alternative-proof, solution-verification, power-towers

I was not clear in my last post :

> Let $0<x$ a real number then we have :
>   $$x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+\cdots}}}}=x$$

I take the logarithm of both side we get :

$$\ln(x)({1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+\cdots}}}})=\ln(x)$$

We can simplify into :

$${1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+\cdots}}}}=1$$

Wich is true recalling the initial equality .

Edit : I prove nothing but see the comment above .

I would learn if you have other proof ?

thanks in advance .

Comment: This is not a proof. It’s circular.

Comment: Oh I see so How to make a proof ?

Comment: First of all, proof of what?  What are you trying to prove?  Youre given a statement of equality, not a theorem.  Equations are solved, not proven.

Comment: The right hand side tells you that $x$ is being defined, and the left hand side gives the definition. If you notice the definition for $x$ is repeated in the exponent.  We can rewrite the equation as $x^{1-x+x}=x$.  That simplifies to just $x=x$ straight away.  It doesnt tell you anything. In fact, I see no obvious reason why $x$ cannot be any positive real number at all.  It may even be possible for $x=0$ or $x<0$. Your manipulations with the natural log simply wouldnt be allowed if $x<0$.

Comment: @SquishyRhode  Thanks so it's trivial ?

Comment: @SquishyRhode what about the infinite case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly let us define the LHS expression. I will assume that we define it as follows
$$x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+\cdots}}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$
Where $a_n$ is the sequence defined by the recurrence relation
$$a_1=x^{1-x}\qquad a_{n+1}=x^{1-x+a_n}$$
Now consider the subsequences given by $b_n=a_{2n}$ and $c_n=a_{2n-1}$. These sequences can be defined by the recurrence relations
$$b_1=x^{1-x+x^{1-x}}\qquad b_{n+1}=f(b_n)$$
$$c_1=x^{1-x}\qquad c_{n+1}=f(c_n)$$
where the function $f:(0,1)\mapsto(0,1)$ is defined by $f(y)=x^{1-x+x^{1-x+y}}$. It is possible to then prove that
$$y\lt x\implies y\lt f(y)\lt x$$
$$y\gt x\implies x\lt f(y)\lt y$$
Then, noting that $b_1\lt x$ and $c_1\gt x$, we can see that $b_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence and $c_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. Using these statements we can also show that $b_n\lt x$ and $c_n\gt x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, $b_n$ and $c_n$ converge by the monotone convergence theorem. We can then show that $b_n$, $c_n$ (and hence $a_n$) converge to $x$ as $n\to\infty$ by solving the equation $f(y)=y$ which has the unique solution $y=x$ for $0\lt x\lt1$. Thus we can finally say that
$$x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+x^{1-x+\cdots}}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=x$$

Comment: The other answer contradict you Where is the problem because both seems to be clear ...?

Comment: Yes you're right so I accept.